# Can somebody clarify the below java code?

Tags: java

```
package cert216;

class example216
{
    public static void main(String args[]){

    int arr[]={1,2,3};

    for(int var : arr)
    {
        int i = 1;

        while(i<=var)
        {
            System.out.println(i++);
            //System.out.println(i+"inside while");
        }
        //System.out.println(i+"outside while");
    }
}
```

Can someone clarify why the output is coming out to be

```
1
2
1
2
3
```

what is the value that var takes while iterating ?, does it start from 0 which is the starting position of arr or does it start from 1 which is the value of arr.

Comment: Please edit your title to be specific to the issue of your Question.

Comment: Well, *that* is not the output from *that* code. See [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/i9pMwZ) showing output to be `1 1 2 1 2 3`. So, try again.

Comment: My ide is showing the above output checked onec again

Comment: I am getting the output as `1 1 2 1 2 3` , so the question is wrong.

Comment: Thanks andreas :)

Answer (score 0):

Just declare the variable 'var' out of the for loop and you will get the desired output.
 You are getting that unexpected output because each time, var was getting element from array it was getting initialised to 1.
 The variable var for each iteration takes elements from array i.e during iteartion-1 it takes 1 then 2 and so on, the array's starting location is 0 and the value at that location is 1 hence var will contain 1 during first iteration. Both are same.

Comment: I got a downvote for no reason? @Anshuman can you upvote it if you are satisfied with my answer!

Answer (score 0):

The analysis is below.,

iter 1:

```
for(int var : arr)  //var =1,
{
    int i=1;
    while(i<=var)    //1<=1
    {
     System.out.println(i++); //prints 1
    }
}
```

iter 2:

```
for(int var : arr)  //var =2,
{
    int i=1;
    while(i<=var)    //1<=2, 2<=2
    {
     System.out.println(i++); //prints 1 and 2
    }
}
```

iter3:

```
for(int var : arr)  //var =3,
{
  int i=1;
  while(i<=var)    //1<=3, 2<=3, 3<=3
  {
    System.out.println(i++); //prints 1, 2 and 3
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kiran for such a nice clarification :)

Comment: Not an issue, But i got the down vote, don't know why!

Answer (score 0):

For of all the result you specified is wrong
the exact result is 1 1 2 1 2 3
while running the first outer loop
value of i=1 and var=1 and the condition(i<=var) satisfies it will enter into inner loop and print 1 then i gets incremented now i=2 now the condition(2<=1) to enter inner loop is false so inner loop will not be executed

while running the second outer loop
value of i=1 and var=2 and the condition(i<=var) satisfies it will enter into inner loop and print 1 then i gets incremented now i=2 now the condition(2<=2) to enter inner loop is true and 2 is printed , i is incremented now i=3 the condition(3<=2) to enter inner loop is false
so inner loop will not be executed.

while running the third outer loop
value of i=1 and var=3 and the condition(i<=var) satisfies it will enter into inner loop and print 1 then i gets incremented now i=2 now the condition(2<=3) to enter inner loop is true and 2 is printed , i is incremented now i=3 the condition(3<=3) to enter inner loop is true and 3 is printed , i is incremented now i=4 the condition(4<=3) to enter inner loop is false
so inner loop will not be executed.
and the result will be 1 1 2 1 2 3

i++ means use then change so it will print value of i and it value is incremented.